# How to prevent adding a new item into the C# Windows Form Listview?

Tags: c#

I'm making a Windows Form that includes a set buttons and listview. It allows user click a button and then show the related product name on the listview, if user click the same button, the product item still continuous add into the listview. But I tried many times that it doesn't work to prevent adding a new item into the listview. I tried the if statement as

```
       if(lvwItemList.Items.Contains(item)){
    lvwItemList.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item});
}
else{
    MessageBox("Record exists");
}
```

, it also doesn't work. How can I prevent adding a same product item into the listview and increase the quantity when I click the same product button? [image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KanMD.png)

```
void TempList(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            SqlCommand tempcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT itemName,quantity,price FROM Products WHERE itemName = @name", con);
            tempcmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = b.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter tempda = new SqlDataAdapter(tempcmd);
            DataTable tempdt = new DataTable();
            tempda.Fill(tempdt);

            foreach(DataRow tempdr in tempdt.Rows){
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(tempdr["itemName"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(tempdr["quantity"].ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(tempdr["price"].ToString());
                lvwItemList.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item});
                lvwItemList.EnsureVisible(lvwItemList.Items.Count - 1);
                TransactionTotalCount = TransactionTotalCount + (decimal)tempdr["price"];
            }
        }
        catch(Exception tempex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(tempex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What makes your listviewitems UNIQUE? The field ItemName?

Comment: Shouldn't the first `if` be `if(!lvwItemList.Items.Contains(item))`?  (You're missing the !)

Comment: I also tried the !, but it still add same item into the listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ContainsKey(string key)` instead of `Contains(ListViewItem` item)

Or :

```
         var txt = textBox1.Text;
            //if (!lvwItemList.Items.ContainsKey(txt))
             if (lvwItemList.FindItemWithText(txt) == null)
            { 
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Text =textBox1.Text;
                lvwItemList.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show ("Record exists");
            }
```

Comment: use  if (lvwItemList.FindItemWithText(txt) == null) it is perfect